# Floating point comparison in Oracle

Tags: oracle, having-clause

I have a query like

```
SELECT
    some_field,
    SUM(float_field)
FROM
    some_table
GROUP BY
    some_field
HAVING
    SUM(float_field) <> 0
```

Is it safe to use such way of comparison in Oracle or it is better to use something like

```
ABS(SUM(float_field)) < PrecisionConstant
```

Just for case, float_field is not nullable field of FLOAT type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the expression `HAVING SUM(float_field) <> 0` will not restrict records where the SUM would be like 0.1 or -0.2.

Use the following expression if you want to achieve that:

```
HAVING TRUNC(SUM(float_field)) <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, actual numbers that are stored in this column have no more than 3 decimal places but it is a kind of legacy table and I can't change the column type from FLOAT to NUMBER(X, 3). So I would like to know whether Oracle can give me the result which will have more then 3 decimal places like 0.000000001 so it will be treated as not equal to zero